# How to control transaction of CMT EJB from client

Tags: ejb

We are trying to build an application, which talks to the remote EJB services and local database. EJB methods are CMT with `TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW`.

My question is: **how can we control EJB transactions from client?**

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? You have different options for transactional behavior and demarcation in the container that are triggered when you call the EJB methods. How different is what you want to do from this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot control EJB transactions from the client. If you're using Container Managed Transactions than you've decided that the container should manage them.

The only "control" over transaction the client has is to re-invoke a method after `EJBException` or the implicit rollback exception.

The client invokes a method with `TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW` and the rest lies in the hand of the EJB Container.